# Foreach through an array with objects and return the values and keys

Tags: php, object

```
array(14) {


[0]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(44)
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Cameras"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(38)
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "Cell Phones"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["set_id"]=>
    int(39)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Computer"
  }
```

The Above is my Data.

I want to return the object names ["Set_ID"] etc and the value.

I have googled and googled and tried examples from here with various failures and now I'm giving up.

I have tried to simply manually return data - ie

```
foreach($result as $results2)
{
    foreach($results2->name as $item)
    {


                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($item);
                echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of flavors of it  I had kind of hoped the above would at least return data and it didn't - just errored.

In the end, I'd like to be able to both pull names and data.  I don't want to have to manually find element names and code it as $result->SET_ID or whatever - I want to be able to just feed SET_ID in as a variable.  I think my problem lies with it being an array of objects and I cant access that object name and all..

Im a noob, so any kind of like detailed explanation wouldn't hurt my feelings so I can learn something.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `foreach($results2->name as $item)` use `foreach($results2 as $item)`. `$results2->name` is not an array thus causing the error.

You can read about object iteration in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

```
foreach($result as $results2)
{
    echo $results2->name.' '.$results2->set_id;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that iteration link. It may be over my head.

My return

From

    foreach($result as $results2)
    {
        foreach($results2 as $item)
        {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($item);   
                    echo "</pre>";
        }
    }


is 

    44
    Cameras
    38
    Cell Phones
    39
    Computer
    60
    CPU

Which is cool, but I need to get the object name (i.e "name" and "SET_ID")

I am eventually going to shove it into a database using the key, or element or whatever those items are called and the associated data so I need  that.

Comment: @user2383622 I think that you want to do `foreach($result as $results2) { foreach($results2 as $key => $item){ ... }}`. This way you can get both the object name (`$key`) and value (`$item`).

Comment: yep. the first foreach he wrote was fine. I will add the full code